# Orbeon Form Builder- Saving User entered data in mySQL

Tags: mysql, orbeon

I have a form created using *Orbeon Form Builder* I have saved and published the form, and when I open it in a new tab this is how it looks like with form controls etc[see picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJvZz.jpg)

and now I want to save the user entered data in MySQL tables.

So I followed the http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html

I added the following to my tomcat/conf/server.xml inside the Engine -> Host tags `

```
    <Context
       path="/orbeon"
       docBase="/orbeon"
      reloadable="false"
  override="true"
  allowLinking="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/mysql" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      poolPreparedStatements="true"
      username="orbeon"
      password="orbeon"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orbeon?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"/> 
 </Context>
```

`
I have also added the following lines to my properties-local.xml

```
    <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.* " value="mysql"/> 
  <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>
```

But when I add sample data to published form and click on the 'Save' button [see picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlpnn.jpg) the MySQL table orbeon_form_data is empty [see picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdOxx.jpg), please help me to save user entered data to MySQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that you set:

```
<property as="xs:string"
          name="oxf.fr.persistence.app.uri.*.*.* "
          value="mysql"/>
```

Instead, you should have:

```
<property as="xs:string"
          name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*"
          value="mysql"/>
```

For more on this, see the [section on the property to set which implementation of the persistence API you want to us](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html#with-a-single-schema).

Comment: Perfect, I'm glad that helped.